# Registration and login script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, mysql

This is a registration and login script I have made in Python 3. It uses a MySQL database. In the future I might use it with my Blackjack game and add a row called `money`, but for now I would like to hear your opinion about this script since I have little to no experience in SQL.

```
import cymysql
from getpass import getpass


def get_user_info():
    while True:
        email = input("Input your Email address (max. 64 chars.): ")
        password = getpass("Input a password (max. 64 chars.): ")
        if len(email) < 64 and len(password) < 64:
            return email, password


def register(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `Password`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (email, password))
    print("You've succesfully registered!")


def login(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s AND `Password`=%s LIMIT 1", (email, password))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if rows:
        print("You've succesfully logged-in!")
    else:
        print("You failed logging-in!")


def check_account(cur, email):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    return row


def main():
    conn = cymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='david'
    )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    email = ''
    password = ''
    email, password = get_user_info()
    check = check_account(cur, email)
    if check:
        login(cur, email, password)
    else:
        register(cur, email, password)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `cymysql.connect` is [a context manager](https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL/blob/master/cymysql/connections.py#L324) and so you should use it in a `with` statement.
2. `conn.cursor` isn't a context manager. Which is very fishy, even more so that the original version of cymysql, pymysql, is.
3. Seperate SQL interactions from UI interactions. This is as multiple parts of the UI may need to use the same SQL interactions, however since they're mangled, it'll lead to code duplication or errors in your UI.
4. You don't need to do `email = ''`, if you want to tell people it's a string then you can do `email: str`. A better thing to do however is use `typing` and make your code fully typed.
5. You may want to verify that the email is a valid email address. It doesn't look like your SQL does that, but I don't know enough about it.

```
import cymysql
from getpass import getpass


def get_user_info():
    while True:
        email = input("Input your Email address (max. 64 chars.): ")
        password = getpass("Input a password (max. 64 chars.): ")
        if len(email) < 64 and len(password) < 64:
            return email, password


def register(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `Password`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (email, password))


def login(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s AND `Password`=%s LIMIT 1", (email, password))
    return bool(cur.fetchall())


def check_account(cur, email):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    return bool(cur.fetchone())


def main():
    conn = cymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='david'
    )
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        email, password = get_user_info()
        check = check_account(cur, email)
        if check:
            loggedin = login(cur, email, password)
            if loggedin:
                print("You've succesfully logged-in!")
            else:
                print("You failed logging-in!")
        else:
            register(cur, email, password)
            print("You've succesfully registered!")
        cur.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, but in my original script I have conn.close() at the end of main(). Should I use it in the updated script too?

Comment: @MariaLaura You're not guarantee to reach the `conn.close()` - If I raise a keyboard interrupt, or kill the script does `conn.close()` run your way?